# Premature End of File error while creating metadata from nodejs

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, node.js

I am trying to create a list view on a custom object from nodejs server. I have constructed a the SOAP(XML) body like I had done [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24543/create-a-list-view-filter-via-apex/24547#24547), but I keep getting the `Premature End of File` error, which doesn't make sense as the XML is properly parsed and the list get created if I do it from salesforce's developer console.

I got a few link, [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008qkrIAA) and [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14221/repeated-outbound-messages), on this error but I was unable to figure out the solution for this.

nodeServer.js:

```
    var https = require('https');
var userSessionId = 'sessionId';
var b = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
b += '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">';
    b += '<soapenv:Header>';
        b += '<ns1:SessionHeader soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:ns1="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">';
        b += '<ns1:sessionId>'+userSessionId+'</ns1:sessionId>';
        b += '</ns1:SessionHeader>';
    b += '</soapenv:Header>';
    b += '<soapenv:Body>';
        b += '<create xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">';
            b += '<metadata xsi:type="ns2:ListView" xmlns:ns2="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">';
                //This is the API name of the list view
                b += '<fullName>Car_Object__c.Merc_View</fullName>';
                b += '<booleanFilter>1</booleanFilter>';
                //Columns you want to display
                b += '<columns>NAME</columns>';
                b += '<columns>CREATED_DATE</columns>';
                //Filterscope should be set to Everything for every one to be able to access this List view
                b += '<filterScope>Everything</filterScope>';
                // Enter the filter that you want to set
                b += '<filters>';
                    b += '<field>NAME</field>';
                    b += '<operation>equals</operation>';
                    b += '<value>Mercedes</value>';
                b += '</filters>';
                b += '<label>Mercedes View</label>';
            b += '</metadata>';
        b += '</create>';
    b += '</soapenv:Body>';
b += '</soapenv:Envelope>';

callMyfunction();

function callMyfunction(){
var options = {
    host : "myhost",
    path : '/services/Soap/m/29.0',
    method: "POST",
    headers : {'Authorization':'Bearer '+userSessionId,
                'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
                'SOAPAction':'Create',
            },
    data : b
    };
    console.log('the '+ JSON.stringify(options));
    var req = https.request(options, function(res){
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        var output='';
            res.on('data',function(chunk){
                output +=chunk;
                console.log('Print the chunk--> \n'+ chunk);
            });
            res.on('end',function(){
                console.log('Final Data is--> \n'+ output);         
            });
    });
    req.on('error',function(e){
        console.log('the erro msg'+ e);
    });
    req.end();  
}
```

Result:

```
Print the chunk-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Premature end of file.</faultstring>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Final Data is-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Premature end of file.</faultstring>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, thanks for prompting me to finally give **NodeJS** a go! I'm pleased to say I've also been able to identify your problem. Looking [through the docs here](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback), i noticed that '**data**' was not a valid member of the **options** structure. What you have to do is utilise the **write** method on the [http.ClientRequest](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest) object returned from the **https.request** method, before calling the **end** method.

```
req.write(b);
req.end();
```

Without this, no data is actually sent, and thus Salesforce claims there is is a premature end to the request, which i would agree is perhaps not the most clear way of say, no data sent.

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew for help! I think I would never have figured this out my self :)

Comment: Your very welcome, i must say it was pretty straight forward to get NodeJS up and running on my Mac and try this out, so thank you for prompting me to have a play with this! Been on my list for a little while. ;-)